# Laravel Request validation exists e nullable ao mesmo tempo

Tags: php, laravel-5

Criei uma classe request e injeto ela no método store da controler. Meu método rules dentro da classe tem a seguinte chave:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
    //...
    'campo_id' => 'sometimes|nullable|exists:tabela,pk',
    //...
    ];
}
```

quando o valor é null e entra nessa validação, ele cai na validação exists e me retorna a mensagem correspondente. Minha intenção é deixar null mesmo. Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score -1):

Pode usar dessa maneira

```
    public function rules()
{
    return [
    //...
    'campo_id' => 'nullable|exists:tabela,pk',
    //...
    ];
}
```

Comment: Estou vendo que o nullable permite que o campo fique null, mas o exists força-o a ter algo. Não funcionou aqui pra mim. Vlw pela força!

Comment: ta usando em uma api ?

Comment: Não amigo, estou usando da forma que coloquei no post. Sem api

Comment: Estou usando dessa forma com api e esta funcionado.

Comment: Encontrei o problema, era em um listener. Realmente funciona!

Comment: Opa parabéns e isso ai

Comment: Coloca como respondido ai para ajudar =D

Comment: Voto e aceitação não devem ser dados por motivos passionais. Vota-se como útil não útil. E aceita-se, de preferência dentre as úteis, a melhor resposta.